# "make" vs "incur" in this sentence

Tags: british-english

> Like humans beings we incur into mistakes.
>
> Like humans beings we make mistakes.

What's the correct sentence in British English?

Comment: Human beings NOT humans beings.

Comment: An adjective is always written as singular (compare with _32-bit architectures_).

Answer (score 9):

Neither; both sentences contain errors:

- 1 & 2: it should be *human beings*, not *humans beings*.
- 1 & 2: *we* does not begin with a capital letter, unless it's at the beginning of a sentence (or unless you're the Queen, referring to herself in very formal documents!)
- 1 & 2: as matter of style, I'd be inclined to separate the two clauses with a comma after *beings*.
- 1 & 2: unless you're an alien, comparing yourself to humans (as in  *we are like human beings*), do you mean "as", rather than "like"?
- 1: it should be *incur mistakes*, not *incur into mistakes*

In terms of meaning, *incur* is typically used to refer to something which you bring upon yourself, e.g.:

> If you submit your tax return after the deadline, you will incur a penalty.

So sentence 2 is probably closer to what you mean. With corrections, it should be:

> As human beings, we make mistakes.

Comment: Yes, you want *as* as the first word here unless the speakers are not themselves human—talking animals or intelligent aliens in a work of fiction, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I find the second one at least easier to understand:

> Like human beings We make mistakes

The subtleties of [incur](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incur) ("bring down upon oneself", "run into") might be correct depending on the general context, but it is easier to relate to the "act of making mistake".
As an aside, I believe you can "incur mistake", not "incur into mistake". It ("incur mistakes") seems however very rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence is normal and natural, but you don't want a capital W in the "we". The first doesn't look right to me and would certainly sound strange even if it was.